# How do I create this complex Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to create a complex Javascript variable like this:

```
var e = {record: {role: {individual: {tag: value}}}};
```

where record, role, individual, and value are variables which come from an array.
At the end it should look like this:

```
var e = {1: {2: {1: {name: Joseph Quincy}
                    {age: 20}    

                 2: {name: Mary Poppins}
                    {age: 40}

                 3: {name: Sebastian Quincy}
                    {age: 60}

            {3: {1: ... and so forth
```

The array was derived from data as shown below, where the first number is record, second is role, and third is individual, the tag is name and age and the value is after the space:

```
name_1_2_1 Joseph Jones
name_1_2_2 Mary Poppins
name_1_2_3 Sebastian Quincy
age_1_2_1 20
age_1_2_2 40
age_1_2_3 60
```

The arrays look like for name_1_2_1 Joseph Jones:

```
key_value_ary = (name_1_2_1, Joseph James);
tag_rri_ary = (name, _1_2_1);
r_r_i_ary = (1, 2, 1);
```

Hence

```
value      = key_value_ary[1]; -> Joseph Jones
tag        = tag_rri_ary[0];   -> name
record     = r_r_i_ary[0];     -> 1
role       = r_r_i_ary[1];     -> 2
individual = r_r_i_ary[2];     -> 1
```

I have all these objects created but I don't know how to write to the final variable "e".
I have the code below that figure out the different values. I write one line at a time so the record may exist already from a previous entry.

```
if (r_r_i_ary.length == 3) {
        var tag = tag_rri_ary[0];
        console.log("TAG", tag);
        var value = key_value_ary[1];
        console.log("VALUE", value);
        const a = {};
        a[tag] = value; // tag value
        console.log("AAA", a);
        const b = {};
        var individual = r_r_i_ary[2]; // individual
        b[individual] = a;
        console.log("BBB", b);
        const c = {};
        var role = r_r_i_ary[1]; // role
        c[role] = b;
        console.log("CCC", c);
        const d = {};
        var record = r_r_i_ary[0]; // record
        d[record] = c;
        console.log("DDD", d);
        e=????? 
      }
```

I obtained this from the console as one of the examples but I need to concatenate all together in one variable:

```
{
    "4": {
        "1": {
            "2": {
                "will_plac": "Atibaia, São Paulo, Brasil"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `d` exactly the object you're looking for?

Comment: could you please make it a [mre] by adding some initialization of the arrays `r_r_i_ary`, `tag_rri_ary` and `key_value_ary`? I'm really not sure how those three are structured and work together exactly.

Comment: d is not because it it overwritten every single time. There are multiple individuals in a role, multiple roles in a record. I don't know how to keep adding more to the variable "e" without destroying it.

Comment: and do you maybe actually want to have `var e = [{record: [{role: [{individual: [{tag: value}]}]}]}];` ?

Comment: @cyberbrain I would like NOT to have arrays but simply objects.

Comment: Maybe use `JSON.parse` to make your live easier? something like `let t = JSON.parse('{"1": {"name": "test"}}')` would give an object that can be accessed like `t[1]` (even though "1" is a string in the json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Valery's, but first I structure the data into a way that is useful:

```
[
  {
    "route": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    "key": "age",
    "val": "60"
  }
]
```

Using `split` and other basic array functions to join what's left back together.

Then I use a function with a while loop to work through the array of the `route` key before setting that value.

```js
const data = [
  `name_1_2_1 Joseph Jones`,
  `name_1_2_2 Mary Poppins`,
  `name_1_2_3 Sebastian Quincy`,
  `age_1_2_1 20`,
  `age_1_2_2 40`,
  `age_1_2_3 60`,
];

const keyedData = data.map(line => {
  const bits = line.split(" ");
  
  const route = bits.shift(); // name_1_2_1

  const keyBits = route.split("_"); // [name, 1, 2, 1]
  const key = keyBits.shift(); // name
  
  return {
    route: keyBits,
    key,
    val: bits.join(' ') // the left over `Joseph Jones`
  }
})


function buildObject(data){
  const finalObject = {}
  
  data.forEach(item => {
    // Reset the target for this item to the `root` object
    let target = finalObject;
    while(item.route.length){
      let routeFragment = item.route.shift();
      // If the target doesn't have a property on this key, create one
      if(!target.hasOwnProperty(routeFragment)){
        target[routeFragment] = {};
      }
      // Now set the new target 
      target = target[routeFragment];
    }
    // Finally, update that value.
    target[item.key] = item.val;
  })
  
  return finalObject
}

const result = buildObject(keyedData);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I look at the object created by keyedData, the route which is an array is empty. It works the way it is but route should not be empty. This is what I see on the console `[{"route": [], "key": "age", "val": "40 anos"},` Why is it empty? Thanks!

Comment: The console shows you that variable at the time you view it — not at the time you console log it. If you change your console.log to `console.log(JSON.stringify(keyedData));` you will see it at that moment in time. You can look into this if you are interested more by googling about how the console works, and how javascript references objects other than primitives.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Will use named capturing groups to parse each line
const lineRegex = new RegExp(
  "^(?<tag>\\w+)" +        // Match and capture the tag in the beginning of the line (word characters)
  "_(?<record>\\d+)" +     // Match and capture the record (digits)
  "_(?<role>\\d+)" +       // Match and capture the role (digits)
  "_(?<individual>\\d+)" + // Match and capture the individual (digits)
  "\\s+" +                 // Match one or more whitespace characters
  "(?<value>.+)$"          // Match and capture the value (any characters until the end of the line)
);

function parse(input) {
  return input
    // get each line separately
    .split('\n')
    // parse it with a regex
    .map((line) => line.match(lineRegex).groups)
    // reduce the parsed lines to the required shape
    .reduce((agg, parsed) => {
      const out = {...agg};
      if (typeof out[parsed.record] === 'undefined') {
        // Make sure there is a record to append to
        out[parsed.record] = {};
      }
      if (typeof out[parsed.record][parsed.role] === 'undefined') {
        // Make sure there is a role in the record to append to
        out[parsed.record][parsed.role] = {};
      }
      if (typeof out[parsed.record][parsed.role][parsed.individual] === 'undefined') {
        // Make sure there is an individual to assign values to
        out[parsed.record][parsed.role][parsed.individual] = {};
      }
      
      // Store the actual value for the tag
      out[parsed.record][parsed.role][parsed.individual][parsed.tag] = parsed.value;
      return out;
    }, {});
}

const data = `name_1_2_1 Joseph Jones
name_1_2_2 Mary Poppins
name_1_2_3 Sebastian Quincy
age_1_2_1 20
age_1_2_2 40
age_1_2_3 60`;

console.log(parse(data));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. What is the meaning of  out ={... agg}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax